Address Sanitizer do not show nothing and lsan_is_turned_off
I'm trying to use address sanitizer in my main.cpp on Windows.

Makefile:
default:
    clang++ main.cpp -o app.exe -fsanitize=address -g
    set ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1 
    ./app.exe


main.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main( void ) {
    auto v = new int(0);
    std::cout << "hi mom" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}


CMD
> make
clang++ main.cpp -o app.exe -fsanitize=address -g
   Creating library app.lib and object app.exp
set ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1
./app.exe
hi mom


I also tried it with dynamic link ( i put the clang_rt.asan_dynamic-x86_64.dll in the same directory )

Dynamic link Makefile
default:
    clang++ main.cpp -o app.exe -fsanitize=address -g -L"C:\Program Files\LLVM\lib\clang\18\lib\windows" -lclang_rt.asan_dynamic-x86_64
    set ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1 
    ./app.exe


So i got:
enter image description here

How can i solve it
I'm one step away to go crazy
The solve of the problem
I would be happy if you send me a Makefile

What shell are you using?  I'd run the program via ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1 ./app.exe but I use GitBash shell.  Is ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1 available on Windows?  The documentation I read says it is only for macOS/Intel and Linux.

Possibly optimized out since you don't use the allocated var at all ? Try printing the var.

'ASAN_OPTIONS' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file.
The pointer value is printed.

Note optimizer can "fix" code, here ASAN finds issue and with -O2 issue is reproduced on gcc. And with -Og and v not in use clang is silent and gcc reports leak
